# Click Windows application and input text using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I would like to use `pywinauto` to control an image processing software.

First, I need to click a specific area (which is used for image dragging) to pop up a windows for path input. I am not sure if there is a better way to use other than `mouse.click(coord)` .

Then, I need to input a path and click the button "OK".

Sorry for not specific for the problem description.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a way to invoke it via keyboard shortcut?

Comment: No, there is no keyboard shortcut. Just an area to click to invoke a pop-up to select folder.

Comment: then in that case I would say mouse.click() might be your best bet. You can first try maximizing your application so that way it will always appear in the same place of your screen , if that’s an issue. After that a dialogue box can be done with {enter}

Comment: After maximizing the application windows, I need to locate the position of the text to click? Any suggestions?